# MySQL Statistics Query Optimization

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm trying to optimize my queries a bit but can't quite get it right.

I'm looking to get some statistics from a table

I have a query for the top contributors

```
SELECT `name`, `amount` FROM `customers` ORDER by `amount` DESC LIMIT 10
```

but I also want to get the SUM and AVG of amount in all records, not just the top 10. I'm not sure how to do this without having a new query for each.

Comment: try use SUM(amount) and group by name

Comment: @MianKhurramIjaz, the OP wants the SUM and AVG in ALL records, not per name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the top 10 users along with the `SUM` and `AVG` of ***ALL*** rows in the table, you can make a cartesian product of the `SUM` and `AVG` like so:

```
SELECT 
    a.name, a.amount, b.amtsum, b.amtavg
FROM customers a
CROSS JOIN (SELECT SUM(amount) AS amtsum, AVG(amount) AS amtavg FROM customers) b
ORDER BY amount DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Keep in mind that the values for `SUM` and `AVG` will be repeating on all 10 rows returned — they will be the same.

If you want the sum and averages of amount for ***each user***, you can do:

```
SELECT a.name, a.amount, b.amtsum, b.amtavg
FROM customers a
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT name, SUM(amount) AS amtsum, AVG(amount) AS amtavg
    FROM customers
    GROUP BY name
) b ON a.name = b.name
ORDER BY a.amount DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
SELECT `name`, `amount`, sa.sum_a, sa.avg_a
FROM `customers`, (select sum(amount) as sum_a, avg(amount) as avg_a from customers) sa
ORDER by `amount` DESC 
LIMIT 10
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use subqueries

```
SELECT 
    `name`, `amount`,
    (SELECT SUM(amount) FROM customers) as summation,
    (SELECT AVG(amount) FROM customers) as average
 FROM 
    `customers` ORDER by `amount` DESC LIMIT 10
```

Comment: Those subqueries would execute for every row in the customers table (considering SELECT is evaluated before ORDER BY and LIMIT). Not very efficient.

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest and typically also fastest way in this case are the two queries.  There is no advantage in fetching the same aggregates ten times.

Make sure that you have an index on `amount`.  That will save you full sorting of the table with each query.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the MySQL `Explain` keyword for query optimization.

For more details you can [click here](http://www.slideshare.net/phpcodemonkey/mysql-explain-explained)

Comment: Hello, normally answers are expected to contain the relevant information here. While it is welcome to cite external resources please include the relevant information here. Thanks.